# How can I read a file and convert the data to numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a txt file that contains

1,2 20000

and potentially read other text files with the same type, only with more numbers like:

1,2,3 30000
or
2,3,4,5 2000000.

```
with open('coordinate.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        pieces = line.split()
        data.append(pieces)
```

and then assign `coord = data[0]`   and   `trial = data[1]`
but coord becomes `["1,2"]` which I just have no clue how to separate 1 and 2 by getting rid of the comma and making into numpy form. How can I appropriately read the file and assign it as the format I want it to be?

Comment: May you use `code sample` to display your code please? It is easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split on multiple delimiters by using a regular expression. Something like:

```
import re
txt = "1,2 20000"
txt_arr = re.split(r'[,\s]\s*', txt)
```

More info [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-split-strings-on-multiple-delimiters-with-python#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20split%20strings%20on%20multiple%20delimiters,6%20Example.%20%207%20output.%20%20More%20)

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to do it is by using the `split` method:

```
pieces = []
lines = None
with open('cooridnate.txt', 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines() # Get lines

for line in lines:
    splitted_line = line.rstrip().split(',') # Split line with "," as a delimiter
    pieces.append({
        'coord': int(splited_line[0]),
        'trial': splitted_line[1:]
    }) # Append the splitted in pieces

print(pieces)
```

You may need to create a loop for trial too (if you want to convert it too).
Is it what you were looking for?